# Android SQLITE! Query more than one data(columns) from the same table

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
public class DatabaseHelper4 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private final static String DBNAME = "Bidprice";
private final static int DBVERSION = 2;

SQLiteDatabase mDB2;

public final static String TBL_BID = "bidprice";
public final static String COL_BID_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public final static String COL_BID_PRICE = "pricebid";
public final static String COL_BID_NAME = "namebid";


private String crt_tbl_bidprice = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_BID + "(" +
        COL_BID_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        COL_BID_PRICE + " TEXT, " +
        COL_BID_NAME + " TEXT " +
        ")";

public DatabaseHelper4(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    mDB2 = this.getWritableDatabase();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(crt_tbl_bidprice);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public long addPrice(String price,String nameprice) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_BID_PRICE,price);
    cv.put(COL_BID_NAME,nameprice);
    return mDB2.insert(TBL_BID,null,cv);
}



public Cursor getLatestPrice() {

    return mDB2.query(TBL_BID,null,null,null,null,null,COL_BID_PRICE + " DESC","1");
}

}
```

I am trying to query more than one data(column) from the table of this database. How do I go about it?I believe it has to do with the formatting of the query statement in my function of getLatestPrice()

Hope I could get some help.Much appreciated

Comment: indeed that is true see my answer for help a little! and please reffer to the links i shared for more advancement in the desired thing of yours! get in comments if you need more assisstence

Comment: I believe my codes are all correct except for the function getLatestPrice(). do you have a solution just to edit that part? Cause i do not want to affect the other codes as this may in turn change the format.

Comment: please refer to my answer below! @jian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a start brother try something like this in the **getLatestPrice** part of yours

```
public Cursor getLatestPrice() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+TBL_BID, null);
  return res;    
}
```

This shall give you the **cursor you require** for now! with all the data in it from the table you want! 
and if you want to get any **specific column/s** and other stuff then you have to do like this for a start

```
public Cursor getLatestPrice() {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String[] projection = {
    COL_BID_PRICE,
    COL_BID_NAME
    };

Cursor res = db.query(
    TBL_BID,   // The table to query
    projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
    null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
    null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
    null,                   // don't group the rows
    null,                   // don't filter by row groups
    null               // The sort order
    );

      return res;    
    }
```

For easier detail and setup reffer to this [link here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

For more advanced and google documentation on this part for android see! [link here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java)

Comment: How do i go about doing it if i want to call COL_BID_PRICE and COL_BID_NAME together?

Comment: @JianMinOng brother see the updated answer ! you just need to declare your array of columns names strings in projections as i did above and it should solve the issue!

Comment: Hi but it doesnt work.there's no errors but nothing happens too.

Comment: @JianMinOng it should ! did you check the data entering part of yours? is there the data present or not?

Comment: Yes i checked my database and it did entered the data in, but it does not display.

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org/blog/version-3-11-1-released/ 

please install it in your system and check whether it shows the data or not?  bcz i reproduces your issue on my side and its working just fine !

Comment: @JianMinOng you accepted the answer please upvote it too! thankyou! so that i could help others too thankyou!